# Restricting package dependencies in .nuspec (ex. '< 0.7' not working)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, versioning, nuspec

I have two c# libraries:

- *main-library*
- *dependency-library* (released in version 0.6 and 0.7)

The *main-library* has the following defined in .nuspec:

```
<dependency id="dependency-library" version="[0.6,0.7)"/>
```

According to documentation for [Nuget Versioning](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning)  this should restrict the *dependency-library* to version 0.6. Inspecting the Nuget.org listing gives the following:

```
dependency-library (>= 0.6 && < 0.7.0)
```

Exactly as expected. Still, Visual Studio suggests to update *dependency-library* to 0.7, and does so without hesitation. I once managed to get an error in a similar situation, giving a message saying that package restrictions stops me from doing an update, whick is what I want. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How are you updating it? What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @MattWard, I am updating through Nuget package installer (right click, _Manage Nuget Packages_), using Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Comment: Sounds like a NuGet v3 bug. I would report it at https://github.com/nuget/home/issues

Comment: It seems a bit strange that such an important feature has a bug like this. Surely, there must be something I am doing wrong?